# Sum of columns based on grouping

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'a': [0,1,0,1,1,1], 'b': [1,1,1,1,1,1], 'c': [0,0,0,0,0,1], 'd': [1,0,1,1,1,0]}
dct = {'a':'top','b':'bot','c':'top','d':'bot'}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

So I have a df and a dictionary that assigns each column to a group. Having trouble creating a function that creates a total(sum) column for the group. This would be the output of the first 2 rows:

| a | b | c | d | total_top | total_bot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

and so on.... Ideally taking the dataframe and name of the group as inputs

Comment: I don't understand this. How are you calculating the sums?

Comment: In the dictionary, a & c have a value 'top'. In the dataframe, I want to sum column a & c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following -

```
sums = df.rename(columns=dct).stack().groupby(level=(0,1)).sum().unstack()
df_new = df.join(sums)
df_new
```

```
   a  b  c  d  bot  top
0  0  1  0  1    2    0
1  1  1  0  0    1    1
2  0  1  0  1    2    0
3  1  1  0  1    2    1
4  1  1  0  1    2    1
5  1  1  1  0    1    2
```

#### Explanation -

1. `df.rename(columns=dct)` renames the column names to `top` and `bot` based on the dictionary `dct`

```
df.rename(columns=dct)

   top  bot  top  bot
0    0    1    0    1
1    1    1    0    0
2    0    1    0    1
3    1    1    0    1
4    1    1    0    1
5    1    1    1    0
```

2. Then `stack()` stacks the rows so you have a single column with 1s and 0s and multiple indexes.

```
df.rename(columns=dct).stack()

0  top    0
   bot    1
   top    0
   bot    1
1  top    1
   bot    1
   top    0
   bot    0
2  top    0
   bot    1
   top    0
   bot    1
3  top    1
   bot    1
   top    0
   bot    1
4  top    1
   bot    1
   top    0
   bot    1
5  top    1
   bot    1
   top    1
   bot    0
dtype: int64
```

3. `Groupby` with `sum()` groups on level 0 (row indexes) and level 1 (column with top and bot values) and sums up the 1s

```
df.rename(columns=dct).stack().groupby(level=(0,1)).sum()

0  bot    2
   top    0
1  bot    1
   top    1
2  bot    2
   top    0
3  bot    2
   top    1
4  bot    2
   top    1
5  bot    1
   top    2
dtype: int64
```

4. `Unstack` to get back the 2 columns `top` and `bot`

```
df.rename(columns=dct).stack().groupby(level=(0,1)).sum().unstack()

   bot  top
0    2    0
1    1    1
2    2    0
3    2    1
4    2    1
5    1    2
```

5. Last, just join the original `df` with this new `sums` dataframe over indexes.

```
df.join(sums)

   a  b  c  d  bot  top
0  0  1  0  1    2    0
1  1  1  0  0    1    1
2  0  1  0  1    2    0
3  1  1  0  1    2    1
4  1  1  0  1    2    1
5  1  1  1  0    1    2
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `map` the columns names to groups
2. `groupby` the resulting values along axis=1 and `sum`
3. `add_prefix` to columns for naming
4. `join` to `df`

```
>>> df.join(df.groupby(df.columns.map(dct), axis=1).sum().add_prefix("total_"))

   a  b  c  d  total_bot  total_top
0  0  1  0  1          2          0
1  1  1  0  0          1          1
2  0  1  0  1          2          0
3  1  1  0  1          2          1
4  1  1  0  1          2          1
5  1  1  1  0          1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `dct` and join back:

```py
grouped = df.groupby(dct, axis = 1).sum().add_prefix('total_')

pd.concat([df, grouped], axis = 1)
 
   a  b  c  d  total_bot  total_top
0  0  1  0  1          2          0
1  1  1  0  0          1          1
2  0  1  0  1          2          0
3  1  1  0  1          2          1
4  1  1  0  1          2          1
5  1  1  1  0          1          2
```